# How can override table in bigquery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

How can I override bigquery table when I load data from appengine backup. I can load perfectly when table does not exists but exist appear a message "Cannot import a datastore backup to a table that already has a schema."

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to append to the table? If not, you could specify the writeDisposition in the load job as WRITE_TRUNCATE, which will cause bigquery to override the table and update the schama at the same time.